# Disable/Hide sensitive information in raise exception Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to hide information when an exception is raised? This is an example of the current undesirable output:

```
[3] pry(main)> User.insert_all!([{email: 'email@email.com'}])
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" of relation "patient_authentication_method_emails" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, null, email@email.com, null).

from /Users/esmerino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" of relation "user_authentication_method_emails" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, null, email@email.com, null).

from /Users/esmerino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
[4] pry(main)>
```

I would like to filter out the email info from them as follows:

```
[3] pry(main)> User.insert_all!([{email: 'email@email.com'}])
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" of relation "user_authentication_method_emails" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, null, [FILTER], null).

from /Users/esmerino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" of relation "user_authentication_method_emails" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, null, [FILTER], null).

from /Users/esmerino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
[4] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Are you asking to filter output in the console? Can I ask why? `filter_parameters` and even `filter_attributes` is unlikely to fix this because what you are showing is an Exception message. This message is managed by the `pg` gem and not rails additionally this functionality would be extremely difficult to implement at the database layer.